# Make a loop to fill null pixels of an image with other images

Tags: google-earth-engine, loop, null, fill

I am new at Google Earth Engine and I want to fill null pixels of an image collection with pixels of complete images. In my case I want to make that in a loop, in which one the first image of a list fill the nulls of the second image and, the resulting image completed, will fill the nulls of the 3er image, and so on. I tried to make it with a iterate function but it didn't work well.

```
//Crear mascara para eliminar datos de nubes
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
            .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

//Introducir shape de cuenca hidrográfica del jucar para delimitar imagenes
var RellenoSE = ee.Image().byte();
var LimiteSE = RellenoSE.paint({featureCollection: SEjucar, width: 5,});
Map.addLayer(LimiteSE, {palette: 'red',opacity:0.5},'SE jucar');

//Filtrado de imagenes por diferentes parámetros
var imagenA =ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
              .select('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12', 'AOT', 'WVP', 'SCL', 'TCI_R', 'TCI_G', 'TCI_B', 'QA10', 'QA20', 'QA60')
              .filterBounds(geometry)
              .filterDate('2018-01-20', '2018-02-20')
              .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',70)
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER',94))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .map(function(image){return image.clip(SEjucar)});
print (imagenA, 'Imagen_filtrada');
//Map.addLayer(imagenA, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'ImagenA');

//Obtener imagenes como una lista de imagenes
var imgList = imagenA.toList (999)
//print ('ListOfImages',imgList)

//Relleno de la primera imagen vacia con una anterior a las fechas de estudio
var imagen_vieja = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
              .select('B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B8A', 'B9', 'B11', 'B12', 'AOT', 'WVP', 'SCL', 'TCI_R', 'TCI_G', 'TCI_B', 'QA10', 'QA20', 'QA60')
              .filterBounds(geometry)
              .filterDate('2017-12-04', '2017-12-06')
              .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE','less_than',70)
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER',94))
              .map(maskS2clouds)
              .map(function(image){return image.clip(SEjucar)});
var imgList2 = imagen_vieja.toList (999);
//var prueba_imagen_vieja = ee.Image(ee.List(imgList2).get(0));
//Map.addLayer(prueba_imagen_vieja, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'Imagen vieja');
var imagen_madre = ee.Image(ee.List(imgList).get(0)).unmask(ee.Image(ee.List(imgList2).get(0)));
//Map.addLayer(imagen_madre, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'Imagen madre');

//Unir 1ª imagen ya rellena a la lista de imagenes que pasarán por el bucle
var imgList_vacia = imgList.remove(ee.Image(ee.List(imgList).get(0)))
//print (imgList_vacia,'lista con 3 img')

var imagen_bucle = imgList_vacia.insert(0,imagen_madre)
print (imagen_bucle,'Lista_imagenes_bucle')

//Realizar bucle para rellenar pixeles de una imagen incompleta con los pixeles de la imagen anterior
  
  //Creacion bucle con iterate para rellenar imagenes
  var inicial = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_bucle).get(0));
  function fillnullclouds (current, previous){
    var LastImage = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_bucle).get(0-1));
    var Updated = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_bucle.get(0+1)));
    var fill = Updated.unmask(LastImage);

    return ee.List(previous).add(Updated)
  }
  
  var imagen_filled = ee.List(imagen_bucle.iterate(fillnullclouds,ee.List([inicial])));
    print (imagen_filled, 'imagen rellena')

  var imagenCollection_filled = ee.ImageCollection (imagen_filled);
  print (imagenCollection_filled, 'imagenCollection rellena')
  
  
  
  //Prueba representación imagen por imagen
  //var prueba_separada = ee.ImageCollection (prueba).toList(999);
  //print ('ListOfImagesFilled',prueba_separada);
  var prueba_imagen0 = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_filled).get(0));
  var prueba_imagen1 = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_filled).get(1));
  var prueba_imagen2 = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_filled).get(2));
  var prueba_imagen3 = ee.Image(ee.List(imagen_filled).get(3));
  Map.addLayer(prueba_imagen0, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'ImagenA Filled0');
  Map.addLayer(prueba_imagen1, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'ImagenA Filled1');
  Map.addLayer(prueba_imagen2, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'ImagenA Filled2');
  Map.addLayer(prueba_imagen3, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'ImagenA Filled3');
//Prueba visualizacion de las imagenes; Saber cuales son completas y cual no, 
//para poder comparar y saber si la función esta funcionando o no
var imagen00 = ee.Image(ee.List(imgList).get(0));
var imagen11 = ee.Image(ee.List(imgList).get(1));
var imagen22 = ee.Image(ee.List(imgList).get(2));
var imagen33 = ee.Image(ee.List(imgList).get(3));
Map.addLayer(imagen00, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'Imagen00');
Map.addLayer(imagen11, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'Imagen11');
Map.addLayer(imagen22, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'Imagen22');
Map.addLayer(imagen33, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 4000}, 'Imagen33');
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't follow exactly how you wanted this to work. Are you looking for the pixel value closest to some "target date", or perhaps you want a pixel from your first (`2018-01-20` to `2018-02-20`) date range, and fall back to a pixel from the second (`2017-12-04` to `2017-12-06`) in case pixels are masked?

Never the less, I think you should have a look at `ee.ImageCollection.mosaic()` and `ee.ImageCollection.qualityMosaic()`. They probably can be helpful in your implementation.

If you want the pixel closest to a "target date" you can do like this:

```
var targetDate = ee.Date('2018-02-01')
var closestedToTarget = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
  .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 70)
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .filter(ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.date('2018-01-20', '2018-02-20'),
    ee.Filter.date('2017-12-04', '2017-12-06')
  ))
  .map(function (image) {
    var daysFromTarget = image.date().difference(targetDate, 'days').abs().multiply(-1)
    return image
      .addBands(
        ee.Image(daysFromTarget).int16().rename('daysFromTarget')
      )
      .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
  })
  .qualityMosaic('daysFromTarget')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e22dcd522b86c0d119e9a0ecc9a0313f

The problem with this is that you are very much reliant on the cloud mask. Another approach is to create median composites for a number of date ranges. Then start to pick pixels from your "preferred" ranges.

```
var dateRanges = [ // We will pick valid pixels based on the order
  ['2018-01-20', '2018-02-20'],
  ['2017-12-04', '2017-12-06'],
  ['2018-12-04', '2018-12-06']
]

var composite = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(dateRanges).reverse()
  .map(function (dateRange) {
    return createComposite(ee.List(dateRange))
  })
).mosaic() // Uses the last non-masked pixel in the collection

function createComposite(dateRange) {
  return ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
    .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 70)
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate(dateRange.getString(0), dateRange.getString(1))
    .map(function (image) {
      return image
        .updateMask(image.select('QA60').not())
    })
    .median()
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d30d09c60d644ccdf29b4f8e57d9ed0d

This example still look terrible. The date ranges are short and cloudy, and the `QA60` band is pretty bad. You can improve the cloud masking by using the `COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY` collection. It slows down the processing, but works a lot better:

```
var dateRanges = [ // We will pick valid pixels based on the order
  ['2018-01-20', '2018-02-20'],
  ['2017-12-04', '2017-12-06'],
  ['2018-12-04', '2018-12-06']
]
var cloudThreshold = 30

var composite = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List(dateRanges).reverse()
  .map(function (dateRange) {
    return createComposite(ee.List(dateRange))
  })
).mosaic() // Uses the last non-masked pixel in the collection

function createComposite(dateRange) {
  var filter = ee.Filter.and(
      ee.Filter.bounds(geometry),
      ee.Filter.date(dateRange.getString(0), dateRange.getString(1))
  )
  return ee.ImageCollection(
      ee.Join.saveFirst('cloudProbability').apply({
          primary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 70)
            .filter(filter),
          secondary: ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY').filter(filter),
          condition: ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
      })
  ).map(function (image) {
    var cloudFree = ee.Image(image.get('cloudProbability')).lt(cloudThreshold)
    return image
      .updateMask(cloudFree)
  }).median()
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/657996ccba8fc1533b8945ece5006146

For the area I ran the script on, it still looks bad, though significantly better then the other approaches. It will work better for less cloudy areas and/or for longer date ranges, where the median composites contain less cloud/haze/cloud shadow/noise.